# What does the .rewind method do on a Tempfile in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stringio

I've looked through [these docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) and Google, and can't seem to find the purpose of `.rewind`, and how it differs from `.close`, in the context of working with a `Tempfile`.

Also, why does `.read` return an empty string before rewinding?

Here is an example:

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.path      # => A unique filename in the OS's temp directory,
               #    e.g.: "/tmp/foo.24722.0"
               #    This filename contains 'foo' in its basename.
file.write("hello world")
file.rewind
file.read      # => "hello world"
file.close
file.unlink    # deletes the temp file
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Rewind** - Read more about it on  [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-rewind)

**IO#Close** - Read more on the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-close)

**Read** - Read more on the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-read)

***Summary***

> **[rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-rewind)**
> Positions ios to the beginning of input, resetting lineno to zero.
> Rewind resets the line number to zero

```
f = File.new("testfile")
f.readline   #=> "This is line one\n"
f.rewind     #=> 0
f.lineno     #=> 0
f.readline   #=> "This is line one\n"
```

> **[IO#close](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-close)**
> Closes ios and flushes any pending writes to the operating
> system.
>
> **[read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-read)([length [, outbuf]])**
>
> Reads length bytes from the I/O stream. Length must be a non-negative integer or nil. ***If length is zero, it returns an empty string ("").***

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you!

Comment: Am glad to help

Comment: I suggest you link to relevant parts of Ruby docs, rather than copying part or all of their contents.That way readers can skip the link if they already know what the doc says. Also, without the link readers may have trouble finding the doc for a fuller read. I suggest, for example, "[IO.close](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#.method-i-close) closes the file and clears any pending writes.". At a minimum, write `close` as `IO#close`